# Why does Linux echo redirection to file add two carriage returns (\r\r) to the file name?

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I have a hello-world style shell script that echoes out the parameters to the screen and also to a local file.

```
echo $1
echo $2
LOGFILE=$2

echo $1 >  $LOGFILE
echo $2 >> $LOGFILE
```

My problem is that the file gets created but has two carriage returns appended to the file name.

For example, if the log file is 'myLogFile.txt'.  What will be on the disk is 'myLogFile.txt\r\r' after the redirection created it.

I am running in a 'sh' command.  A command sample is 'sh myscript.sh AAA myLogFile.txt'.

Comment: You created the script file on Windows, so it has CRLF line breaks. Use `dos2unix` to fix it.

Comment: Yes, I did write the .sh in Windows.   Is dos2unix a standard Linux command I should find easily?  Should it be in the /bin folder?

Comment: It depends on the distribution, some have it by default. If you don't have it, you should be able to install it easily.

Comment: Perfecto.  Thank you